# Нужна C# библиотека для приема почты на русском в различных кодировках

Tags: c#, imap, pop3

Пишу клиента Pop3/Imap на C#, но столкнулся с проблемой кодировки при приеме писем. Кто может посоветовать бесплатную библиотеку C# корректно принимающей письма на русском в различных кодировках.

А то использовал библиотеку S22, SystemMail, ImapX везде одно и тоже, вопросы вместо букв ?

На Pop3 пробую провести разбор писем

```
List<OpenPop.Mime.Message> mails = FetchAllMessages(Properties.Settings.Default.ServerPOP, Properties.Settings.Default.PortPOP, Properties.Settings.Default.SSL, Properties.Settings.Default.Login, Properties.Settings.Default.Password);
            MessageBox.Show("Загружено " + mails.Count.ToString() + " писем");

            for (int i = 0; i < mails.Count; i++)
            {
                CMail mail = new CMail();

                mail.DateMessage = Convert.ToDateTime(mails[i].Headers.Date);
                mail.NumberMessage = i;
                mail.Subject = mails[i].Headers.Subject;

                mail.Messages = EncodingString(mails[i].MessagePart.Body);

                if (mail.Parse())
                    messages.Add(mail.Message);
                else
                {
                    List<string> er = new List<string>();

                    er.Add(mail.NumberMessage.ToString());
                    er.Add(mail.Subject);
                    er.Add(mails[i].MessagePart.BodyEncoding.BodyName);
                    er.Add(mail.Messages);

                    Write(er.ToArray());

                    File.WriteAllBytes("log2.txt", mails[i].RawMessage);
                }
            }

private string EncodingString(Byte[] data)
    {
        if (data == null)
            return string.Empty;

        ICharsetDetector cdet = new CharsetDetector();
        cdet.Feed(data, 0, data.Length);
        cdet.DataEnd();
        if (cdet.Charset == null)
            return "";

        var enc = Encoding.GetEncoding(cdet.Charset);

        return enc.GetString(data, 0, data.Length);
    }
```

однако вместо букв там

```
=FB=C9=D2=C9=CE=C1 =DA=C5=D2=CB=C1=CC=C1 (=D3=CD):
=F7=D9=D3=CF=D4=C1 =DA=C5=D2=CB=C1=CC=C1 (=D3=CD):
=E4=C9=C1=C7=CF=CE=C1=CC=D8 =F4=F7 (=C4=C0=CA=CD=CF=D7): 55 (136*85=D3=CD)
=F7=C1=DB=C9 =D0=CF=D6=C5=CC=C1=CE=C9=D1:
```

Comment: А аутлук настроенный есть? Можно через аутлук и пространство имен Microsoft.OfficeInterop.

Comment: Не Outlook отсутствует

Comment: Мы в проекте использовали ImapX и никаких проблем с кодировкой не возникало. Покажите код получения сообщения, может быть Вам смогут помочь с решением проблемы

Comment: Пробовал использовать ImapX, однако при  вызове  var uids = client.Folders.Inbox.Search("ALL", ImapX.Enums.MessageFetchMode.Headers);  программа отваливалась

Comment: Почему  var uids = client.Folders.Inbox.Search("ALL", ImapX.Enums.MessageFetchMode.Headers); не работает?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Есть C# порт [Mozilla Universal Charset Detector](https://www.nuget.org/packages/UDE.CSharp)

```
    IBuffer buffer = await FileIO.ReadBufferAsync(file);
    DataReader reader = DataReader.FromBuffer(buffer);
    byte[] fileContent = new byte[reader.UnconsumedBufferLength];
    reader.ReadBytes(fileContent);    
    ICharsetDetector cdet = new CharsetDetector();
    cdet.Feed(fileContent, 0, fileContent.Length);
    cdet.DataEnd();
    if (cdet.Charset != null)
        string text = Encoding.GetEncoding(cdet.Charset).GetString(fileContent, 0, fileContent.Length);
```

1. После получения письма конвертируете текст в массив байт
2. С помощью этой библиотеки узнаете кодировку
3. конвертируете ранее
   полученный массив обратно в строку с уже известной кодировкой...

Comment: В принципе библиотека работает, однако в некоторых письмах не распознает кодировку и выводит =FB=C9=D2=C9=CE=C1 =DA=C5=D2=CB=C1=CC=C1 (=D3=CD):

Comment: поищите методы вроде `Uri.DecodeString()` (пример для UWP, для WinForms должны быть аналоги). Так по сети бегает кириллица в основном.